# How to shoot lasers from Ship(XNA)?

Tags: xna, textures

I want a code which allows me to shoot multiple lasers from my Ship. Its a 2D game and the laser TEXTURE2D moves in a straight line.
My Solution:
I use `List<> class` of my `Laser` Class.

```
List<Laser> laserlist = new List<Laser>();
```

Can anybody tell me another solution other than using `List<> class`? I am new to XNA.

Comment: Pretty broad question. Can you edit your question to include details on what you've tried, and exactly what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well actually my problem is that I want to find another method other than using List Class, if there is any.

Comment: If you told us why you're looking for another method, as in, what problems you're currently having with the List class, we'd better be able to suggest something.

Comment: what's the matter with the list?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your question might be more to do with what the best use of particular Collections is in C#. Lists are usually the easiest way to have a dynamic set of objects; there are some specializations for particular optimizations (if you have a collection of thousands that needs a fast access time)

Some other possibilities for you to know, but there's no need to change course:

Set< Typename > : The most distinct differences that come to mind are that Sets are unordered, so that you don't know which order they'll be in when you iterate. It's also, by definition, impossible to have the same object listed in a Set twice.

Typename[] (array) : Useful if you know exactly how many of the type you can have at most, or if you have a reasonably good guess and want to maintain performance (since you need to initialize them with a particular size).

Dictionary< Typename1, Typename2> : If you want to be able to access, say, a Laser, by its name, then you could initialize a Dictionary, and then retrieve the one you want with `dict["lasername"]`. Doesn't sound too useful for your case, but keep it in mind.